# Asp.net web service needs to return NTFS File Permissions of Windows Principal rather than the service itself

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, ntfs

We're running an ASP.net web service that needs the ability to upload, rename, delete and view files on a central server, based on the NTFS permissions of the user or the AD groups he/she is a member of.  AD users access this service remotely as well as locally.  We're using Windows Authentication (not Kerberos).

I've written some code that checks the NTFS permissions for read and write access (code is at the bottom of the post).  It shows them only the folders they have read data access for, and hides the upload/edit/delete options for those they don't have write data access.  It works well when I'm running in localhost on my machine.  **The problem is** when I publish to a QA server, **I get the permissions of the service, not the remote user.**  The article below explains why this is happening.  Unfortunately, we can't use Kerberos authentication at this point.

**I'm pretty much out of ideas. Any options I'm not considering?**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx
**Using Impersonation with Windows Authentication**
By using impersonation, ASP.NET applications can execute code or access resources with the identity of the authenticated user or a fixed Windows identity. ***Standard impersonate-level impersonation tokens that are usually created when you enable impersonation allow you to access local resources only.*** *To be able to access remote network resources, you require a delegate-level token. To generate a delegate-level token when you impersonate, you need to use Kerberos authentication and your process account needs to be marked as trusted for delegation in Active Directory.*

I tried `<identity impersonate="true" />` in my Web.config, but got this error  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.`

My next attempt was to do temporary impersonation within just the HttpGet method on my controller.

```
IIdentity WinId = User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();
  try
  { //GET Method of ActionResult
    var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
    var userName = user.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
  }
```

Retrieving the userName shows I can successfully impersonate a user, but I still only have the file permissions of the service.

This is my code to check NTFS permissions for folder level access.

```
    public static bool CheckPermission(string path, string accessType)
    {
        bool hasReadAccess = false;
        bool hasWriteAccess = false;
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            DirectorySecurity acl = dir.GetAccessControl();
            AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            WindowsIdentity currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(currentUser);
            foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
            {
                FileSystemAccessRule fsAccessRule = rule as FileSystemAccessRule;
                if (fsAccessRule == null)
                    continue;
                if (accessType.ToLower() == "readdata")
                {
                    return hasReadAccess = CheckReadAccess(fsAccessRule, principal);
                }
                if (accessType.ToLower() == "writedata")
                {
                    return hasWriteAccess = CheckWriteAccess(fsAccessRule, principal);
                }
            }
            return hasReadAccess;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is my CheckReadAccess method.  CheckWriteAccess is essentially identical.

```
    public static bool CheckReadAccess(FileSystemAccessRule fsAccessRule, WindowsPrincipal principal)
    {
        bool hasReadAccess = false;

        if ((fsAccessRule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadData) > 0)
        {
            SecurityIdentifier sID = fsAccessRule.IdentityReference as SecurityIdentifier;

            if (sID != null)
            {
                if (principal.IsInRole(sID))
                {
                    if (fsAccessRule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                    {

                        return hasReadAccess = false;
                    }
                    else if (fsAccessRule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
                    {

                        return hasReadAccess = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return hasReadAccess;
    }
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that your QA environment is on a separate server with identical locations and permissions?

Comment: That is correct.  The QA server I mentioned is a web server which is hosting the service, but would have a similar environment to the production web server.  Paths and permissions we're trying to access are on a separate file server.  Thanks for your response.  I'm a newbie to programming, but have been thrown in the deep end of the pool on this one.

Comment: This blog is essentially what we're needing to do, without using Kerberos. I'm not overly optimistic we'll find a way to do it.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/